# Change Display Scaling in Remote Desktop Session

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I need to change display scaling settings in a remote desktop session when connecting to a VM. So far I've tried various Powershell methods that only seem to work when connecting via the vSphere console. These do not appear to work in a Remote Desktop session.

I found on [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/rdp-files) that I can edit the .rdp file to include `desktopscalefactor:i:<VALUE %>`. So, I did this, but there was zero effect, even after logging off and rebooting the VM.

How can I accomplish this? I should also note that I cannot install another client. I have to use the pre-installed Remote Desktop Connection client.

**My Laptop**: Windows 10 21H2

**VM**: Windows 10 21H2

**Remote Desktop Version**:

Shell - 10.0.19041

Control -10.0.19041

RDP 10.8 supported

**.rdp file**:

```
screen mode id:i:2
use multimon:i:0
desktopwidth:i:3840
desktopheight:i:2160
session bpp:i:32
winposstr:s:0,1,0,0,1920,1020
compression:i:1
keyboardhook:i:2
audiocapturemode:i:0
videoplaybackmode:i:1
connection type:i:7
networkautodetect:i:1
bandwidthautodetect:i:1
displayconnectionbar:i:1
enableworkspacereconnect:i:0
disable wallpaper:i:0
allow font smoothing:i:0
allow desktop composition:i:0
disable full window drag:i:1
disable menu anims:i:1
disable themes:i:0
disable cursor setting:i:0
bitmapcachepersistenable:i:1
full address:s:REMOVED
audiomode:i:0
redirectprinters:i:1
redirectcomports:i:0
redirectsmartcards:i:1
redirectclipboard:i:1
redirectposdevices:i:0
autoreconnection enabled:i:1
authentication level:i:2
prompt for credentials:i:0
negotiate security layer:i:1
remoteapplicationmode:i:0
alternate shell:s:
shell working directory:s:
gatewayhostname:s:
gatewayusagemethod:i:4
gatewaycredentialssource:i:4
gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:0
promptcredentialonce:i:0
gatewaybrokeringtype:i:0
use redirection server name:i:0
rdgiskdcproxy:i:0
kdcproxyname:s:
drivestoredirect:s:
desktopscalefactor:i:200
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the line "devicescalefactor:i:180" to the end of the file and it will work. (Yes, it's different from displayscalefactor)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).